# Moving through a Multi Page Application in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm structuring a Multi Page App in angular. I have a main app with its ngRoute configured so that the resulting url is something like:

http://localhost:8080/project/main#firstTemplate
http://localhost:8080/project/main#secondTemplate
http://localhost:8080/project/main#thirdTemplate
...

Now I must move to another app in the same project so that the Url is something like:

http://localhost:8080/project/secondary#fourthTemplate

I'm able to achieve this by manipulating the string resulting by $location.absUrl() and pass it to $window.location.href but it's horrible.

Is there a better way to do the same thing?

Comment: Are you using 2 abstract states in $stateProvider?

Comment: I'm not using AngularUI Router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this by the means of your router. There is a default router in angular, though I would suggest you going with https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router - as I think it is much better than Angular v1.x defaults.

With that router you can define few states (1 state per each URL), define URL for each state, define views to be displayed in that state, actions on entry/leave etc. Then, you can get access to $state object and its go() method to switch between states - as well as easily have it done automatically on  elements by specifying .

Comment: I see that with AngularUI Router I can do nested view and routing. But what if I just need to pass from an App to a complete different one.

Comment: Then you should use just regular window.location way, <a href="..."> or any other standard.